# Deck of cards combination probability

Tags: probability, combinations

> Suppose that a deck of $36$ cards is divided between $4$ players into
>   equal sized piles. One of the players claims that he has two queens.
>   What is the probability that he has one more queen and at least one
>   ace?

The probability of having one more queen and at least one ace is equal to the $1 -$ probability of having no more queens and no aces, which is given by
$$P(A) = 1 - \frac{28}{34}\cdots\frac{22}{28},$$
since we exclude two queens and four aces (six cards in total) from all other possible outcomes of seven remaining cards. Am I right?

Comment: You have not explained which cards are included in the deck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, the deck consists of four aces, four kings, four queens, four  jacks, four $10$, four $9$, four $8$, four $7$ and four $6$.

Comment: ".... that he has one more queen..." or "...that he has *exactly* one more queen..."? By the first option I think your solution is correct.